# how to deploy apk specific for older android versions

Tags: android, google-play

- I have an app available for android on google play
- I'm willing to make it runnable for api level >= 15
- One of the apis I use in my app is crashing on api level < 20, so in order to make it run fine i need to import a third API (only for those versions, it looks like android has included the required components in newer versions)
- How can a build an apk and tell google play to use this apk (larger since it includes more apis) only for api level < 20 and still use the other one for the newer version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it right you need multiple APKs for different API levels

This is the relevant Google documentation for that https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-apks/api

This done with the use of `minSdkVersion` and `maxSdkVersion`

ie.
- "older support" you can use `minSdkVersion = 15` and `maxSdkVersion = 19` 
- for newer APIs `minSdkVersion = 20` without defining any max version.

Then you have to use different Version code in these apps with a sophistigated pattern for application versioning:

Check [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks) the `Using a version code scheme`

eg. [image]